# How to get data from ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send some data using ajax from file, where I use jQuery UI Sortable to a file which must do something with that data.

In first file ajax start working on stop event:

```
stop: function(){

        var data = 5
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            url: "ajax.php",
        });
    }
```

It works perfect, file ajax.php starts to work on every stop event in the first file. But I don't know, how to send a data to ajax.php.
If I put in ajax.php this, it's not working:

```
$filed = "save.txt";
$rez = $_POST['data'];
file_put_contents($filed, $rez);
```

resume: This post can't be deleted, because it can helps to another users. But single helpful comment, which was a correct answer to a question (by @Jeff), was deleted. Genius logic. Thanks to everybody, have a good fun on your social

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions. Regarding your edit, you need to adjust your expectations considerably: **you are not owed help by volunteers**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data needs to be an object.

Example:

```
stop: function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {name: name, lastname: lastname},
        url: "ajax.php",
    });
}
```

In case of form could be:

```
data: $('#form').serialize();
```